# Are these cubic rings the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the pure cubic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10})$ then as $10\equiv 1 \pmod 9$ then the integral basis for $K$ is of the form $\{1,\sqrt[3]{10},\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}\}$. And the ring of integers

$\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus \mathbb{Z} \sqrt[3]{10} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}$ which is the maximal order in $K$.

I also have found out that the field $K$ has a power integral basis that is of the form

$\biggl\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3},\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}\bigr)^2\biggr\}$  which gives the ring

$R=\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus \mathbb{Z} \frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}\Bigr)^2$

My teacher says that the above rings are the same thing and they represent the same unique maximal order in $K$ (if I understood him correctly)

To show that these are the same I computed the index $[\mathcal{O}_{K}:R]=1$  which means that $\mathcal{O}_{K}=R$
but the maximal order is unique for every number field, can I conclude then that 
 $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ and $R$ are the same rings (maximal order), but expressed by different integral bases?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the change of bases matrix? If its coefficients are integers, and it has determinant $\pm1$, then that will do it. If ${\mathcal O}_K=R$, then this should be the case.

Comment: yes, the determinant of the transition matrix is $-1$. So I can conclude by saying that since the index is $1$ these rings are essentially the same and represent the unique max order?

Comment: Yes. And no *essentially* about it. They are exactly the same set of numbers :-)

Comment: Great! Thank you Jyrki!